# Fair distribution of verticles on a Vert.x cluster of nodes

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I've been experimenting with Vert.x high availability features to test horizontal scalability and resiliency. I have a cluster of several nodes based on Hazelcast. I'm creating verticles on any nodes via an HTTP API. Verticles have the `HA` flag set when they are created.

#### Testing scalability

If I have `n` nodes `Nn` loaded with HA-verticles and if I add one additional node there is no verticle that is migrated from the `Nn` node on the new one so that the load would be balanced. Is there a way to tell Vert.x to do so, or not ? I believe it's not so simple...

#### Testing  resilience

If I have `n` nodes `Nn` loaded with HA-verticles and I kill one of the nodes, all the verticles from that very node are migrated, but are migrated on one single of the remaining nodes that is not always the least loaded one. That destination node may become overloaded and the whole cluster would be at risk of freeze or crash. Same question as before: is there a way to *force* Vert.x to balance the restarted verticles on all nodes, or at least on the node that is the least loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observations are correct, there is no way:

- to distribute verticles from a failed node over the rest of the nodes
- to prevent starting verticles in a node that is already loaded

Improving the HA features is not on the Vert.x roadmap.

If, as it seems, you need more than basic failover, I would recommend to use specialized infrastructure tools that can leverage info from monitoring systems and start/stop new nodes as needed.

Comment: Hummm. I was afraid someone would answer that! Thanks.